# CSS not connecting to .asp files

Tags: html, css

Im having a problem with my css not connecting with the rest of my web pages. I did this in my default.asp and it only seems to connect to the main page. How can I make it connect to the rest of the pages?

```
   <html>
   <head>
    <title>LaserVault Workflow -- Custom Reporting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WFSTYLE.CSS" />
   </head>

   <body>

     <center><h2>workflow</h2></center>

    <ul>

    <li><a href="WorkFlowErroredItems.asp">WorkFlow Errored Items with Age</a></li>
    <br>
    <li><a href="reports.asp">Forms Report</a></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ".. the rest of the pages"? Are there more .asp pages? If so, then include this css in all of them if needed.

Comment: i mean in the workflowerroreditems.asp and the reports.asp